# How to Import Class From Inside the Main function of another file?

Tags: python, oop, import, python-import, python-class

I want to import a class defined within the main() function of another file to my current script.
Here is the code:

File A.py

```
def main():
    class Aclass()
          def foo(self):
               return x
```

I want to include the above Aclass in my current file but when I import A.py I get the error:
no attribute 'Aclass"

Comment: Why are you defining the class in a function? Your function doesn't do anything with that class, so after the function executes, that class ceases to exist. If it did, for example, return it, you could do something like `import A; Aclass = A.main()`

Comment: Things that are defined inside a function are local to the function. The problem is the same as if you wrote `x = 3` inside `def main():`, and then wanted to import `x` from another file. To get information back from a function, `return` it. Further, the code inside a function is only relevant *if and when the function is called* - that's the *purpose of* a function.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're declaring the class inside a function, so you will be able to import main() but not Aclass(). Just move your class definition outside the main function and that will do the trick

Comment: If I rewrite main() to return AClass that doesnt work either. I want to do it without moving my class definition out side the main() if possible

Comment: Why? It make no sense to define the class in the function in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you want by that but You can return that class when you run that function.

For example:

```py
def main():
    class Aclass():
        def __init__(self):
           pass
    return Aclass

f = main()
y = f()
```

Your class's object now is y variable

Your way in writing code is not correct but every one has thoughts or ideas that they want to do it.

Comment: And yes you can return many classes from function and you can do anything you want to do but I don't understand your idea.

Comment: Thank you. I realize now I was importing the class definition and I needed to use '()' to instantiate.